# Connection refuse from external tab

Tags: facebook, ssl, security

I've just created a contact form in a free domain and I want to include it in my facebook application. I've configured my application, but when I go to my app, it shows me this message : `Errore 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Il server ha rifiutato la connessione.` 
How can I solve the problem? The SSL certificate is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the SSL certificate is required. No SSL, no App/Tab.

Comment: Ok, but can i have a free SSL certificate for testing my app? Do you know something similar? Thank you!

Comment: Facebook itself does not give out SSL certificates to developers. You need to check if your hoster is offering free SSL certificates. But I don't think they do it...